# How to filter nodes based on edge properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

[image: Sample graph]

We have a Neo4j graph that keeps track of people walking through doors.  It contains Person nodes, Door nodes, and WALKED_THROUGH edges. The person and door nodes have a "name" property, and the edges have an "action" property that is set to either "Entered" or "Exited".

The question I need to answer is this: Given a specified person, what are the names of the doors that has she entered at least once, but never exited?

I can easily get the relevant paths:

```
match( (person:Person{name:'Mary'})-[walkedThroughEdges:WALKED_THROUGH]->(doors:Door) )
return person, walkedThroughEdges, doors
order by doors.Name
```

...which yields this:

```
╒═══════════════╤════════════════════╤═════════════════╕
│"person"       │"walkedThroughEdges"│"doors"          │
╞═══════════════╪════════════════════╪═════════════════╡
│{"name":"Mary"}│{"action":"Exited"} │{"name":"Door B"}│
├───────────────┼────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│{"name":"Mary"}│{"action":"Entered"}│{"name":"Door B"}│
├───────────────┼────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│{"name":"Mary"}│{"action":"Entered"}│{"name":"Door A"}│
├───────────────┼────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│{"name":"Mary"}│{"action":"Entered"}│{"name":"Door A"}│
└───────────────┴────────────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

...but I can't figure out how to manipulate the results to get the answer I need. In this case, the expected answer is "Door A", because Mary entered Door A at least once but never exited through it.  Door B should be excluded, because Mary exited through that door.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A door should be included in the results if 1) it has one or more Entered edges; AND 2) it has zero Exited edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this could work...

How about you only match `WALKED_THROUGH` edges where the action is 'Entered'. And then OPTIONALLY MATCH each of those person, door pairs where an `Exited` edge exists. Then return the person, door combinations where the `Exited` match does not exist.

```
MATCH (person:Person {name:'Mary'})-[:WALKED_THROUGH {action: 'Entered'}]->(door:Door)
WITH person, door
OPTIONAL MATCH (person)-[exited:WALKED_THROUGH {action: 'Exited'}]->(door)
WITH person, door, exited
WHERE exited IS NULL
RETURN person, door
```

Another approach would be to match them all. And then only return the ones where there are entered and no exit. This might make more sense as I would suppose a person has to enter before they can contemplate exiting.

```
MATCH (person:Person {name:'Mary'})-[walked_through:WALKED_THROUGH]->(door:Door)
WITH person, door, collect(walked_through.action) AS walked_through
WHERE ALL(action IN walked_through WHERE action = 'Entered' )
RETURN person, door
```

Yet, one more approach is not use `NOT EXISTS`. The most obvious looking of the three possibilities.

```
MATCH (person:Person {name:'Mary'})-[walked_through:WALKED_THROUGH]->(door:Door)
WHERE NOT EXISTS((person)-[:WALKED_THROUGH {action: 'Exited'}]->(door))
RETURN person, door
```

Comment: The NOT EXISTS approach is admirably simple, and it gives me the correct results in my tests.  Many thanks, Dave!

Comment: It is, however, not as efficient as the other 2 answers, since it needs to query the DB twice. By the way, the `EXISTS()` function is not needed -- you can just directly use the pattern passed to it.

Comment: agree, the ALL() answer is comparable to cybersam and Inversefalcon's answers. NOT EXISTS is the most obvious to read though.

Comment: Yes. Your answer's second query is actually nice and succinct compared to the other 2 answers.

Comment: I appreciate cybersam's comments about efficiency.  For the small graphs we're working with right now, simplicity and readability are paramount, but if we ever scale up, those considerations will be important.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: If you just need doors where the user has only ever entered, this should work.

```
match(person:Person{name:'Mary'})-[walkedThroughEdges:WALKED_THROUGH]->(door:Door) 
with person, door, collect(walkedThroughEdges.action) as actions
with person, door, size(filter(action in actions where action = "Entered")) as enteredCount, size(actions) as total
where enteredCount = total
return person, door
order by door.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

This query should find the doors that a person had ever used for entering but never for exiting. *It is similar to @InverseFalcon's approach, but uses different syntax.*

```
MATCH (person:Person{name:'John'})-[r:WALKED_THROUGH]->(door:Door)
WITH person, door, r.action AS action, COUNT(*) AS ct
WITH person, door, COLLECT({action: action, ct: ct}) AS x
WHERE SIZE(x) = 1 AND x[0].action = 'Entered'
RETURN person, door, x[0].ct AS num_enters
ORDER BY door.Name;
```

The first `WITH` clause uses [aggregation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/#query-functions-aggregating) to get a count of the number of times the person performed each `action` for each door.

The second `WITH` clause uses aggregation to collect the action/count pair(s). *There can be either 1 or 2 pairs since there are 2 possible actions.*

The `WHERE` clause checks that the collection only has a single action/count pair and that the action is "Entered". If that is true, then the relevant door was entered but never exited.